# WHY does eclipse automatically remove my code inside the project?

Tags: android

I was working on a project. I deleted the project from the workspace (not from disk) temporarily to work on another project. I'm sure that I had saved my work before doing this. After finishing with second project I deleted it from workspace and imported the first project but there was nothing of my codes. Everything was removed. the files (classes, layouts, etc) all of them were in the project but they were empty. I checked the files on the disk and unfortunately saw that what is inside eclipse is real! All the files were empty and all my codes gone. I wanna ask WHY should this happen?

Comment: Use some scm tool like git to prevent these things.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me also. You have to make a copy of your project on your disk first. Then you open it with eclipse and click to "copy projects into workspace" and then it works :)
Say if it's ok !

Comment: What should I do now? I need my code. I don't wanna start from the beginning. It's a shame for google with this IDE

Comment: I think you have to start from scratch... But for next time you will know how to open. (I think when you tried to open your project it has been deleted completely)